# Need help understanding the bounds for $\phi$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this question from my textbook:

The solid bounded below by the sphere $\rho=2\cos\phi$ and above by the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Find the spherical coordinate limits for the integral that calculates the volume of the given solid and then evaluate the integral.

[image]

The solution states that $\phi$ goes from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I don't understand this. They get $\pi/4$ by changing $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ into spherical coordinates and solving for $\phi$. I understand the process however since the cone is bounded below by the sphere and above by the cone, why aren't the limits from here to here:

[image]

i.e why isn't it going from that angle between the z-axis and $\rho=2\cos\phi$ to $\phi=\pi/4$ (which is the angle that is formed at the boundary $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: The region where $0\le \phi\le \frac {pi}{4}$ is above the cone and below the sphere, (or bounded above by the sphere and below by the cone).  The region $\frac \pi 4\le \frac \pi 2$ is above the sphere and below the cone.

Comment: I guess I’m just confused on how to measure the angles on the z axis? Isnt the vertical line of the z axis when $\phi=\pi/2$? Or is that wrong way of looking at it?

Comment: Conventionally, $\phi = 0$ corresponds to the z-axis.  However, you can generate perfectly consistent spherical coordinates with $\phi = \frac \pi 2$ corresponding to the z-axis.

Comment: Ohh okay thanks that helps clarify things! So when $z=0$ I.e. the xy-plane, that’s when $\phi=\pi/2$?